# How to analyze data in which participants are free to generate any number of responses per trial?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, multivariate-analysis, random-variable, multinomial-distribution

In an abstract sense, this is my experiment:

- Participants get 10 trials, half with stimulus type A, half with stimulus type B.
- They then generate responses (the number of which is unconstrained and can vary from trial to trial). (1)
- These generated responses can belong to one of seven categories.

I want to know if getting stimulus type A vs. stimulus type B makes a person more or less likely to generate any of the seven types of responses.

The complications are that: participants generate a variable number of responses per trial; observations are not independent but nested within trials for a given stimulus.

What is the most appropriate analysis for this kind of data?

---

1 - This isn't really relevant to the question (I don't think anyway), but if you're curious why there are a variable number of responses: participants are generating clues to get their partner to guess some answer. They generate responses until their partner guesses the correct answer. That is why the number of responses varies from trial to trial.

---

Edit: A further complication, that I missed initially, is that there were an unequal number of trials for each stimulus type (10 for Stimulus Type A; five for Stimulus Type B).

Comment: I don't understand your statement "They then generate responses until their partner achieves the goal".

Comment: I'll edit to take that out. It doesn't really affect the question–all that's important is that each trial has a variable number of responses.

Comment: That really didn't help.

Comment: Added a footnote to explain.

Comment: The footnote is vague.

Comment: Are the partner pairings the same from trial to trial? Stacking the data up sequentially by trial (1 to 10), stimulus (A or B), ordinal count of responses (1 to some unconstrained number) and time between responses (e.g., in seconds, minutes, hours or days, as appropriate...this could be cumulative), an indicator to signal the partner pairing, as well as the response type (1 to 7) would generate an analyzable, sequential matrix of information that would be amenable to a hierarchical mixed model.

Comment: Thanks, DJohnson. Yeah, every participant has the same partner for each trial. So, essentially, each row will be a response, and I also have a variable that indicates how many other responses were given for that particular trial?

Comment: That matrix, as you're describing it, would lose the granularity and information available from the varying number of responses. Explicitly incorporating those effects would allow you to more accurately decompose the contributions to variance in the model and, therefore, your understanding of the behaviors.

Comment: Are you wondering about how large the number of clues is, or about the proportion of clues that fall into each category (or both)? How many clues are typically given? How many trials are there?

Comment: Want to know if the number of clues that fall into each category differs for Stimuli Type A and Stimuli Type B. There were an average of five clues per trial. There were 10 trials for Stimulus Type A and five trials for Stimulus Type B (I missed this further complication in my initial post).